# How to stop QMdiArea Expansion

Tags: c++, qt

I am using QMdiArea in my application. Application always opens in fullscreen  mode. when I add around 10-12 subwindows, to mdi area and try QMdiArea::tileSubWindows() it causes application to expand beyond full screen. I have to do my application showNormal() then showMaximize() to bring application in desired state. How can I disabled this undesired expansion of QMdiArea ?

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I'm facing it right now and `showNormal()` followed by a `showMaximize()` inside my custom MDI Area class doesn't help. Also because of the expansion the scrollbars don't show. Only if I move a subwindow outside of the visible area of the screen or put the application's window in float and not maximized mode these get visible.